# Why is Wolverine not able to walk or run properly in Logan?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In *Logan*, Wolverine seems to have a problem in his right leg from his first appearance. We can see that until the last scene before he took the full dose of the drug, he was barely able to run.

What caused that is not specified anywhere in the movie. Is there any information available on it?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/what-is-happening-to-logan

Comment: But what injury he has in his leg that his body is not able to heal? if adamantium metal is the cause, then how it is affecting only his right leg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Logan is dying from Adamantium Poisoning. Prior to the scene in question though, he was brutally beaten by a younger clone of himself, adding to his existing injuries. He collapsed a day later, and it took injections of a green healing serum to help get him better. ***It still took 3 days for it to work enough to wake him up***. They were carefully injecting him with a little at a time due to the side effects of the drug (extreme rage, loss of control, and adverse effects on normal healing). **By using it, it helped heal but left him weak, exhausted.**

And then he used a full vial of it, pretty much guaranteed he would be near death when the body in strength ran out. Red Bull sucks like that.

**So his limp running is a direct result of a week of constant injuries and drugs on top of his illness.**

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: We are never told specifically why Logan is limping.

Several times throughout the film, there is mention of some ailment "inside me" which Logan suffers from. The ailment is never given a name, but we are to presume it is likely some form of cancer or something fairly nasty. (**Correction**: user- CyberClaw pointed out in the comments that Logan suffers from "Adamantium poisoning" -- thank you!) The fact that Logan is suffering from a sickness for any length of time is testament to the decreased effectiveness of his regenerative mutant super-powers.

As the viewer, we should presume that Logan is limping because of either of two things:

1. The degenerative disease or sickness that ails him.
2. A serious wound from a previous altercation which never fully healed, due to his decreasingly effective regenerative powers.

Comment: Logan does give a name to his ailment. Adamantium poisoning (like in the comics). He says it in passing to X23.

Answer (score 3):

Logan's limp comes from the film "The Wolverine" in a scene when he's chasing down the girl someone shoots him in the thigh, ever since then he's had a limp (the only problem, he went back in time from days of future past possibly eliminating this experience entirely) but its still possible this happened a second time.